# Formula alteration

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

is there any way to transform the formula$ \frac {1-x}{x-3}$ into something that can be easily sketched, or which will help eliminate $x$ from the denominator?

Comment: Can you provide some context?

Comment: if you want to sketch, even only in general the graph above, you need to make it look like some recognizable form, so the x in the denominator has to go...question is how...

Answer (score 1):

You can write it as follows: $$\dfrac{1-x}{x-3}=\dfrac{(-x+3)+1-3}{-(-x+3)}=\dfrac{(-x+3)}{-(-x+3)}+\dfrac{-2}{-(-x+3)}=-1-\dfrac2{x-3}.$$
Does this help you enough? By the way a more general process for doing such tasks is known as [partial fraction decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition).